# Powerpoint Delete Shapes just on a part of a slide

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I am currently trying to delete shapes (ink shapes drawn by the user and retained when presentation was finished) on a slide with a macro. It looks like this:

```
Sub EraseInkOnSlide(oSl As Slide)
' Erases any INK shapes drawn by the user and
' retained when the user quits the slide show
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim x As Long
    With oSl.Shapes
    For x = .Count To 1 Step -1
        If .Item(x).Type = 23 Then
            .Item(x).Delete
        End If
    Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Now I just want the macro to delete the ink-shapes on a part of the presentation, for example in a specific square on the slide.

Is this possible, if so how?

Comment: Before deleting the item, add a few more tests. If its .Top and .Left are equal to or greater than the .Top and .Left of the square AND if its .Top + .Height is =< the square's .Top + .Height AND if its .Left + .Width =< the square's .Left + .Width THEN delete it.

Comment: Works charmingly! Thank you very much! Maybe write it as an answer, so i can set it as the best working answer?

Comment: Glad it helped, but better yet, why don't you post the code that's working as the answer; that should be more useful to more people than my undetailed suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Steve i got it to work. Here is the code:

```
Sub EraseInkOnSlide(oSl As Slide)
' Erases any INK shapes drawn by the user and
' retained when the user quits the slide show
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim x As Long
With oSl.Shapes
For x = .Count To 1 Step -1
    If .Item(x).Type = 23 Then
        If ((.Item(x).Top >= "square.top") And (.Item(x).Left >= "square.left")) And (.Item(x).Top + .Item(x).Height <= "square.top" + "square.heigth") And (.Item(x).Left + .Item(x).Width <= "square.left" + square.width") Then
        .Item(x).Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```

The "square.x" stands for your specific coordinates you set for your square.